# Why am I getting problems with username & password for WP cron?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I'm trying to set up cron in Wordpress (& I'm only familiar with Drupal). I have the following set up in cron which doesn't work, and when I paste the url into a browser I get 'ERROR: invalid username and/or password'. Yet the user (Cronjob) is in WP and I can logon to WP using the password, and has the required permissions set for CiviCRM.

usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 'http://example.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=Cronjob&pass=xxxxxxxx&key=2c3b60639d70ba87f61e819cb2cd0e67'

Comment: Just a thought but in /wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php, do you have the owner permissions set to execute (744).  By default, I think they are set to 644.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the single quotes around the path to cron.php, once I removed them it worked.  Also usr/bin/wget was incorrect, just needs wget. Here's the working crontab entry with output redirected for debugging.

wget -O - -q -t 1 [http://example.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=Cronjob\&pass=xxxxx\&key=2c3b60639d70ba87f61e819cb2cd0e67](http://example.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?name=Cronjob%5C&pass=xxxxx%5C&key=2c3b60639d70ba87f61e819cb2cd0e67) > /home/example/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/cronerrors.txt 2>&1